# How do i make my "BruhSoundeffect.wav" play when an else statment is called. If a person gets the answer on the question wrong it plays an effect

Tags: java, javasound

```
public class ThreeDoors {

    private String message;
    private String answer1;
    private String answer2;
    private String answer3;


    public ThreeDoors()
    {

        answer1 = "ECHO"; //I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have no body, but I come alive with wind. What am I?
        answer2 = "CANDLE";//You measure my life in hours and I serve you by expiring. I’m quick when I’m thin and slow when I’m fat. The wind is my enemy.
        answer3 = "MAP";//I have cities, but no houses. I have mountains, but no trees. I have water, but no fish. What am I?


    }

    public int getRandom()
    {
        Random randy = new Random();
        return randy.nextInt(11 - 1) -10;


    }

    public String getQ1()
    {
        return "I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have no body, but I come alive with wind. What am I?";
    }
    public String getQ2()
    {

        return "You measure my life in hours and I serve you by expiring. I’m quick when I’m thin and slow when I’m fat. The wind is my enemy.";
    }
    public String getQ3()
    {

        return "I have cities, but no houses. I have mountains, but no trees. I have water, but no fish. What am I?";
    }

    public String getA1()
    {

        return answer1;

    }
    public String getA2()
    {

        return answer2;

    }
    public String getA3()
    {

        return answer3;

    }




}
```

That is the blueprint class above, and my main method is below. Im a novice coder, please take it easy on me :).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class ThreeDoorsDB {

    //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html
    //I saw that if advanced sequencer methods are not needed then you can just use a clip.
    //Using the open method of the clip, which contains a audio input stream.
    //Now I can take my clip object and open the AudioInputStream.
    //I use a try statement to make sure the program does not crash if an exeption is thrown.
    //An invisible JFRAMe is used just to play music because it is easier to do it in jframe than JOP.
    //The imports came in with the errors, thanks intellij.
    //Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: big.mp3 (The system cannot find the file specified)

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, LineUnavailableException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(false);

        try {
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("big.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.start();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ThreeDoors demo = new ThreeDoors();
        int rando1 = demo.getRandom();

        ImageIcon recap = new ImageIcon("bruh.png");
        String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number generated = " + rando1, "Trivia", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, recap, null,"");

        int rando = Integer.parseInt(input);

        if (rando == rando1)
        {
            ImageIcon correct = new ImageIcon("cor.png");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Acess Accepted", "Trivia", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, correct);

        }
        else
        {
            ImageIcon stop = new ImageIcon("Israeli_Stop_Sign.png");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Acess Denied", "Trivia", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,stop);
            System.exit(0);

            JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame1.setVisible(false);

            try {
                AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("bruh.wav"));
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audio);
                clip.start();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        ImageIcon ear = new ImageIcon("bigbrain.png");
        input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, demo.getQ1(), "Question 1", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ear, null, "");

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(demo.getA1()))
        {
            ImageIcon ok = new ImageIcon("loam.png");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Correct!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,ok);

        }
        else
        {

            ImageIcon no = new ImageIcon("no.gif");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Incorrect!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, no);

            System.exit(0);
        }

        ImageIcon light = new ImageIcon("unnamed.png");
        input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, demo.getQ2(), "Question 2", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, light,null,"");

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(demo.getA2()))
        {

            ImageIcon yes = new ImageIcon("prime.gif");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Correct!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, yes);

        }
        else
        {

            ImageIcon nope = new ImageIcon("giphy.gif");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Incorrect!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, nope);

            JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
            frame.setVisible(false);

            try {
                AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("bruhsound.wav"));
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audio);
                clip.start();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);


        }

        ImageIcon mount = new ImageIcon("mount.gif");
        input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, demo.getQ3(), "Question 3", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, mount, null, "");

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(demo.getA3()))
        {

            ImageIcon yup = new ImageIcon("yt.gif");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Correct!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, yup);

        }
        else
        {
            //Mark Cuban > Everyone
            ImageIcon nah = new ImageIcon("Mark.gif");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Incorrect!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, nah);
            System.exit(0);

        }

        ImageIcon gold = new ImageIcon("god.png");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "CLAIM THE GOLD!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, gold);



    }

}
```

As you can see when a person gets a question wrong, they should be prompted with a sound effect, but it does not work. The original background audio in the beginning of the main class works, but the same thing does not in the else statement. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I figured I could move the JFrame above the JOptionpane in the else stametent.